# Serverless variable from external file nested property

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-serverless

I have serverless yml and a config file

**config file**

```
 app: {
   port: 3000,

 db: {
   connectionString: 'xxxxx'
 },
  lambdaDeploy:{
   stage : "DEV",
   region : "es-west-1"
 }
```

Trying to use these variables in yml like below

**yml**

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: ${file(./appconfiguration.json).app.stage}
  region: ${file(./appconfiguration.json).app.region}
```

But its reading and taking default

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The syntax used here is not correct.

```
stage: ${file(./appconfiguration.json).app.stage}
```

Use colon instead:

```
stage: ${file(./appconfiguration.json):app.stage}
```

More details here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-in-other-files